# Is it posssibile do this check

Tags: sql, database, oracle

In my query i need to check if a parameter is null or not so I do som operation
I know I can use "is","is not" operation to do thies but I don't want:

I need to check if value in db with an input parameter are null or can be checked:

```
 nvl(as.happy,null)=nvl(?,null) // I know this is  gives me error
```

I need to check if "as.happy is not null check with ? parameter" if "as.happy is null check with null value". does it exist some function that let me to do this?

Comment: Why don't you want to use is/is not? To avoid passing ? twice, perhaps? Please edit your question to explain you reason and constraints. (And the nvl code you showed shouldn't error, but is pointless.)

Comment: It exists but you don't want to use it

Comment: Not sure, but would this be okay : `as.happy=nvl(?,as.happy)`

Comment: @LukStorms That would fail when `as.happy` is `null`.

Comment: There is one trick that could work. But you need to know what kind of values `as.happy` contains. F.e. if it's an integer with only positive values in the data. Then NVL both to a negative.  `nvl(as.happy,-42)=nvl(?,-42)`. Basically defaulting nulls to what doesn't exist in the data.